# How do I get google assistant to work with bluetooth headsets?

Tags: google-assistant

I got google assistant to work on my Galaxy A12 but it only responds when I'm not not using bluetooth. How can I control my assistant via a bluetooth headset?

Comment: Did you find/follow: https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/9027902?hl=en#zippy=%2Cwireless-headphones